# Rails - how can I add a data attribute to a fields_for select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, custom-data-attribute, html-select

I'm using

```
<%= fields_for @reservation do |r| %>
  ....
  <span data-to="date">
    <%= r.select :end_day, options_for_select((0..7).map{|offset| Time.zone.today + offset}) %>
  </span>
  ...
<% end >
```

to identify the element through the span but I would rather identify the select control itself and apply the data-to to it (not the individual options, though that will be next).

I tried

```
 <%= r.select :end_day, options_for_select((0..7).map{|offset| Time.zone.today + offset}), data:{to: 'date'} %>
```

but the attribute didn't show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <%= r.select :end_day, options_for_select((0..7).map{|offset| Time.zone.today + offset}), {}, data: {to: 'date'} %>
```

Because signature is:

```
select(method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

Comment: yeah, that's weird.  Its +1 and accept for me!  Thanks for the good answer (as usual).

Comment: I got -1 on the q also!

Comment: At least we've balanced each other :)